# Hyperlink control using List box in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, farm-solution

Is it possible to add a list of hyperlink controls in list box in c#? If possible, how can I do this? Also, I have two textboxes: one for Title and other for URL. When I add a new item, the values in the text boxes must be added to list box as a hyperlink where, title is the hyperlink title, and URL is the hyperlink URL. Can anyone help me?

Comment: By default, you cannot add hyperlinks into ListBox control

Comment: OK. then is there any other option to place a list of hyperlinks?

Comment: Can you please post the code which you have tried..

Comment: Is is asp.net, wpf, winforms??

Comment: Actually i need this for my share point application. it is visual webpart @Mahesh Malpani

Comment: Then Tag it accordingly!!

Answer (score 0):

This code is very simple but hope this will get you started.
I added a ID to the link so you can have 2 of the same Display Values with different links. Hope this helps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Hyperlink_control_using_List_box
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<hyperlinks> hll = new List<hyperlinks>();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hyperlinks link1 = new hyperlinks();
            link1.hyperlink_id = 1;
            link1.hyperlink_name = "Google";
            link1.hyperlink_link = "www.google.com";
            hll.Add(link1);

            hyperlinks link2 = new hyperlinks();
            link2.hyperlink_id = 2;
            link2.hyperlink_name = "Facebook";
            link2.hyperlink_link = "www.facebook.com";
            hll.Add(link2);

            hyperlinks link3 = new hyperlinks();
            link3.hyperlink_id = 3;
            link3.hyperlink_name = "Yahoo";
            link3.hyperlink_link = "www.yahoo.com";
            hll.Add(link3);

            listBox1.DataSource = hll;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "hyperlink_name";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "hyperlink_id";
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (hyperlinks link in hll)
            {
                if (listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() == link.hyperlink_id.ToString())
                {
                    label1.Text = link.hyperlink_link;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class hyperlinks
    {
        public int hyperlink_id { get; set; }
        public string hyperlink_name { get; set; }
        public string hyperlink_link { get; set; }
    }
}
```